# Simplified Fraction.

Tags: fractions

My son has been set homework with half-completed fractions along a line of $30$. He has to complete the missing half.

For example, there is an indicator at the $10$th line and the fraction is half completed with a $1$ on the top half; therefore, he completes it with a $3$, making $\frac13$.

However, on the $13$th mark, there is a line with the number $2$ on the top half of the fraction. On my understanding, $13$ over $30$ is the lowest that the fraction can be reduced to. Why then is it calling for a $2$?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at the wrong line, and you should be getting $\frac{12}{30} = \frac{2}{5}$?

Comment: @pjs36 That is because I first read it as 'H' and 'E', like an acronym, instead of 'he' (which I understood later on). I thought someone else may also be confused, therefore explicitly stated that he refers to his son.I don't think there is any problem in doing so.

Comment: In all likelihood, either you are looking at the wrong line (as angryavian said), or the tick mark is put in the wrong place. You are right that it makes little sense if the tick mark is at the 13th place along the line, for then the answer would be $\frac2{\frac{60}{13}}$, which probably not what the teacher wants.